# Picture and animateinline

Tags: graphics, animate

I would like to have an animation (consisting of three pictures pic-0.jpg, pic-1.jpg, pic-2.jpg) with additional elements added on the top of the animation.
What am I doing wrong? And how can I do it right?

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames,svgnames,table},11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{animate}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\only<1>{Text}
\only<2> 
{\begin{animateinline}[autoplay,loop]{6}
   \multiframe{3}{i=0+1}{ 
   \begin{figure}[h!]
   \centering
   \setlength{\unitlength}{0.1\textwidth}
   \begin{picture}(0,0)
   \put(-6,-3){\includegraphics[height=0.8\columnwidth]{pic-\i} }
   \put(4.5,-2){$x$}
   \end{picture}
   \end{figure} }
 \end{animateinline}      }  

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Several issues: (1) `figure` environment inside `animateinline` environment; (2) zero `picture` size

Comment: Thanks. I got rid of the issues. I still does not work.

Comment: The error is: package animate error content of first frame must not have zero width

Answer (score 1):

1. `\begin{picture}(0,0) ... \end{picture}` produces a box with zero dimensions, but `animate` wants non-zero size boxes in order to produce animation frames.

   TikZ is better suited for annotating external graphics files. Dedicated TikZ-based packages exist for image annotation, e. g. `callouts` on CTAN, and non-CTAN **`onimage`**, introduced [↗here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9559). I prefer the latter. It can be downloaded as **`onimage.dtx`**[↗here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/%7Etex-sx/tex-sx/development/view/head:/onimage.dtx). Run **`pdflatex`** twice on it to get **`onimage.sty`** and the documentation **`onimage.pdf`**.

---

2. The **`figure`** environment should be moved out of the **`animateinline`** environment.

---

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{onimage}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Annotated animation}
  \only<1>{Text}
  \only<2>{% 
    \begin{figure}\centering
    \begin{animateinline}[autoplay,loop]{1}
      \begin{tikzonimage}[width=0.6\columnwidth]{example-image-a}[tsx/show help lines]
        \draw (0.5,0.5) [<-]-- (0.3,0.4) node [anchor=east] {centre};
      \end{tikzonimage}
    \newframe
      \begin{tikzonimage}[width=0.6\columnwidth]{example-image-b}[tsx/show help lines]
        \node [anchor=south west] at (0,0) {lower left};
      \end{tikzonimage}
    \newframe
      \begin{tikzonimage}[width=0.6\columnwidth]{example-image-c}[tsx/show help lines]
        \node [anchor=north east] at (1,1) {upper right};
      \end{tikzonimage}
    %\newframe  
    %\multiframe{3}{i=0+1}{
    %  \begin{tikzonimage}[width=0.6\columnwidth]{pic-\i}[tsx/show help lines]
    %    ... 
    %  \end{tikzonimage}
    %}
    \end{animateinline}%
    \caption{annotated animation}
    \end{figure}
  }
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```